# How to connect to red5 server automatically?

Tags: flash, red5

I am using red5 server for video recording. But when using for video recording, it ask for "connect to Red5 server"

How to connect automatically to server? so that user can directly record video

Answer (score 1):

All you must do is specify a method to run when the FlashPlayer loads your swf. Inside this method create an NetConnection and execute a connect() on the url for your red5 server.